# Call jQuery widget from outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-widgets

I wrote a jquery-Widget with a method `clear`:

```
(function($) {
    $.widget('ccf.mobileHeaderAutocomplete', {
        ...
        clear: function () {
            this.ulElement.empty();
        },
        ...
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I sucessfully call another method on the input element:

```
$('.header-searchfield input')
    .on('input', function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $(this).mobileHeaderAutocomplete('suggest', value);
    });
```

I now want to call it when clicking a button (outside the input element, to which the widget is attached to), but it doesn't work:

```
$('.header-searchfield__close-button').on('click', function () {
    $('.header-searchfield input').data('mobileHeaderAutocomplete').clear();
}
```

The error in the JS console is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clear' of undefined`

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8506683/2725515) answer as reference and tried also `ui-mobileHeaderAutocomplete`. Am I missing something here?

Comment: this.Element.empty() maybe?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to call `$('.header-searchfield input').mobileHeaderAutocomplete("clear")` ?