# Chessboard doesn't resize with the css `media` event (chessboard.js)

Tags: html, css, chessboard.js

I have created a multiplayer chess game with node.js and chessboard.js, and everything worked fine until I started testing on devices with smaller viewports than mine (I have 24"). The problem was that the board didn't fit on the screen! Well, to make the chess game available to both bigger and smaller viewports, I used `media` in `CSS`:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #my-board {
       width: 500px; // My board is 800px at the begining.
    }
}
```

Now here is the catch: The board doesn't resize. Or, rather, it does resize, but after the user has refreshed his/hers screen, which sucks because the game uses socket.io, and if he/she refreshes, the algorithm thinks that the user has disconnected (which leads to giving the user who is left the credit of winning).

Here is the smallest reproducible sample (you have to have chessboard.js library installed):

```
<html>

<head>



<!-- I am using bootstrap -->

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<style>

#myBoard {
    width: 700px;
}



.main-container {
    text-align: center;
}

#container {
    height: 30%;
}

body {
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

#gameboard {
    text-align: center;
}

#chessboard-background {
    height: 95%;
    /* width:auto; */
}

#scroll-pgn {
    max-width: 700px;
}

#liveAlertPlaceholder {
    margin: 20px;
}

</style>
<body>
        <div id="chessboard-background" class="container overflow-auto text-center rounded-4 bg-dark text-white text-emphasis-dark position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle">
            <div id="gameboard" class="text-center m-2 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="body">
                <div id="myBoard"></div>
                
                </div>                
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this possible to fix? Or is it integrated with the chessboard.js library itself? Thank you for any answer.

**EDIT**

Full code: https://github.com/marsianjohncarter/Chess

**LIVE (might load a bit)**

https://chess-website-completed.onrender.com/

Comment: In the source code, the chessboard initialization starts around [line 748](https://github.com/oakmac/chessboardjs/blob/bfb9315cd44d22c4a3ccc883ab4c0b42e902557e/lib/chessboard.js#L748) and includes calculating a static size for the squares, board, etc, that is created/injected into the element that's passed in to the initialization function, e.g. `let board = Chessboard('myBoard')`. This returned value is a "widget" according to line 1809, which seems to be a jQuery Widget. It has a builtin resize method, but I've tried modifying the example and can't get it to resize on window size change.

Comment: No problem :) Can usually find trouble, but much harder time understanding how to fix it or avoid it, lol. Tried getting the widget from the element, like [the A to this Q mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506621/accessing-widget-instance-from-outside-widget), but it was against the minified version so that may have been part of the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the `<head>` section of your page. You can do container queries too, btw.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This css works:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1039px) {
  body > main{
    padding: 16px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1040px) {
  body > main{
    padding: 36px;
  }
}
```

Comment: I already have.